# A cylinder is not homeomorphic to a disk

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

A teacher told us that a cylinder can't be homeomorphic to a disk, but he was unable to give a 'simple' proof; the only proof he knew uses the fundamental group which I've never seen in my life. Any hint for something simpler ?

Comment: An open disk removed 1 point is a open-cylinder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint [for the original question about circles and cylinders]: removing any two points from the circle results in a disconnected space.

Hint [for the revised question about disks and cylinders]: conceptually, the disk and the cylinder can both be given the structure of manifolds with boundary, but the boundary of the disk is connected and that of the cylinder is not. You probably can make this argument rigorous without knowing about the fundamental group or simple connectivity, but I don't think it would be worth the effort.

Comment: This is nice, but intuitively, how can you give the cylinder a structure of manifold with boundary ?

Comment: Think of forming the cylinder by rolling up a flat piece of paper. The hard bit is not showing that the cylinder is a manifold with boundary but in giving a topological characterisation of the boundary points of the manifolds.

Comment: ok, but since the cylinder is 'infinite', it's more like rolling an infinite piece of paper; this is still considered to have 'edges' ?

Comment: The unqualified term "cylinder" in topology is normally used for "closed" cylinders: the cylinder on the circle $S^1$ is $S^1 \times [0, 1]$ not $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$. I suspect most people trying to answer your question have been taking the former reading (and assuming you mean a cylinder on a circular base). If  $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$ is a cylinder for you, then it is not compact, so you don't need to worry about connectivity properties to distinguish your cylinder from a disk (which is compact).

Comment: Oh you're right I'm talking nonsense, sorry. Well I liked your argument, take those 15 points

Comment: No need to apologise! Have 5 points on me.

Answer (score 1):

Think that the lines on the cylinder are arcs. If you remove one point from the cylinder then the arc that used to pass through that point won't matter because you can connected any two points with an arc from the "back " of the cylinder. So it's still "something" like convex. But if you remove any point from the interior of the disk, then convexivity is dead.This needs charts of the manifolds and many more. It's not worth it.
This is not maths(what i wrote you), but you really cannot prove this without fundamental group because everything you will may think as  a proof will be connected to the fundamental group .

Comment: Ok thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the point is that the disk is *simply connected*, i.e. every loop can be continuously deformed to a point, while a cylinder is not so.

(By the way, being simply connected is equivalent to saying that the fundamental group is trivial.)

Comment: I can see why the disk is simply connected, but intuitively, why the cylinder isn't ?

Comment: Oh because of the 'belt'  ? You can have a loop that encircles the cylinder, and it can't be deformed to a point. Right?

Comment: Right. $\,\!\,\!$